# access application receive not found do i've to setup a domaine name

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I've made all files (deployment, pods, services, ingress ) to install an application. When I go to [https://{POD_NAME}/moddev1/auth](https://%7BPOD_NAME%7D/moddev1/auth), I get the message

> 404 Not Found

from nginx.

I guess that the message is coming from nginx ingress.
All the informations are sent to the port **443**. 
Currently, I've the following pods running {xx98, xx97}.

Do I have to set a specific domain name to access to this application?

I'm a little bit lost at the moment... :(

Comment: Have you set up a DNS to hit your ingress controller? Could you post the content of your Ingress resource yaml? 'kubectl get endpoints --all-namespaces' and 'kubectl get ingress' would also be helpful

Comment: you will find all the information on the link https://gist.github.com/zyriuse75/f81bc7f04114df20059ebb8815771db9

Comment: thanks for your help @Ryan Dawson

Comment: I think you're going to need to hit one of the hosts in your ingress config (https://gist.github.com/zyriuse75/f81bc7f04114df20059ebb8815771db9#file-kubectl-get-ingress-namespace-poc-nginx-ingress-yaml-L43) I'm guessing you are trying to hit one of your tea or coffee services. If it's something else you're trying to access then I think you need to add it to the ingress definition. Are you working from an example like https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/complete-example ?

Comment: i read the example on github and i tried to do the same but i think i make a mistake or they forget something :(  . when i try to access to `http://cas.cloud.corp/moddev1`  i get cant find website :( i put my ingress and service yaml on the gist gist.github.com/zyriuse75/7529ed78edb86cd635a90934ba37de48

Answer (score 0):

The ‘404’ is a good thing as the POD is being found. It seems the error is that it can't find the ‘/moddev1/’ path. Found the same issue at [1] with a workaround that you should try.

[1]https://github.com/jetstack/kube-lego/issues/115

Comment: how can i set a new domain in k8s ?  i already have `cloud.devlan.corp` but i would want `cas.cloud.devlan.corp`

Comment: the thing is when i go to `https://cloud.devlan.corp/moddev1/auth`  i dont have 404 iget cant access to the website :(

Answer (score 0):

the solution to my issue was

i make a mistake when i set  serviceName on ingress 
the good one was 
`serviceName: https-cas`

Also i set my domain `cas.xxx` now i cans access

```
 tls:
  - hosts:
    - cloud.devlan.efg.corp  
    - cas.devlan.efg.corp
    secretName: cloud-devlan-efg-corp-cert
```

if you have the **error 404** when you try to access to your web page that mean you access until the proxy **Nginx** and your mistake is on ingress file . Maybe the same as me ;)